# Bash: back quotes and eval confusing behavior

Tags: linux, bash, unix, freebsd

Can someone explain the second result?

```
user$ set 5 5
user$ n=2
user$ eval echo \$$n
5
user$ echo `eval echo \$$n`
10268n
```

10268 is bash pid.

GNU bash, version 4.0.35(0)-release (i386-portbld-freebsd7.2)

UPD: This works fine:

```
user$ echo `eval echo \\$$n`
5
```

But then...

```
user$ echo `eval echo \\\$$n` #3
5
user$ echo `eval echo \\\\$$n` #4
10268n
user$ echo `eval echo \\\\\$$n` #5
10268n
user$ echo `eval echo \\\\\\$$n` #6
$2
user$ echo `eval echo \\\\\\\$$n` #7
$2
user$ echo `eval echo \\\\\\\\$$n` #8
$2
user$ echo `eval echo \\\\\\\\\$$n` #9
10268n
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
set 5 10
```

makes positional parameters `$1=5` and makes `$2=10`

This line:

```
n=2
```

Sets shell variable `n to value 2`

Then this line:

```
eval echo \$$n
```

is effectively this:

```
echo $2
```

prints `$2` which is `10`

Finally this line:

```
echo `eval echo \$$n`
```

is same as (due to back ticks):

```
eval echo $$n
```

which is effectively this:

```
echo $$n
```

Prints `$$` (current shell PID) and literal `n` hence prints

```
10268n
```

Comment: There are no single quotes. There are back quotes. I dont understand how does it works. I expected the output to be the same.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I meant back-ticks only. Effectively echo `eval echo \$$n` is same as `eval echo $$n` which is same as `echo $$n` I already have this in my answer.